# How to pass parameter to ContentTemplateSelector?

Tags: c#, wpf, contenttemplateselector

I want the `TemplateSelector` to select a template based on the country. 
So, for `MyDataTemplateSelector:SelectTemplate` to receive the country I bind `Content` of `ContentPresenter` to `CountriesComboBox`.
The problem is that the returned template is not bound to `City` or `Streets`. I think it happens because `DataContext` of the selected template is not bound to the ViewModel, and thus, bounded properties of the tamplate are not accessible.

I tried the code below, but in my opinion, it doesn't work since the `Content` of `ContentPresenter` is bound to `CountriesComboBox` and not to `{Binding}` as it should be. But, if I bind `Content` to `{Binding}`, I won't have access to the selected item of `CountriesComboBox` from TemplatrSelector.

So, how do I do this?

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Readonly_CellEditingTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Editable_CellEditingTemplate">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Streets}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:MyDataTemplateSelector ReadonlyTemplate="{StaticResource Readonly_CellEditingTemplate}" EditableTemplate="{StaticResource Editable_CellEditingTemplate}" x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="City">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" Content="{Binding ElementName=CountriesComboBox, Path=SelectedIndex}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <ComboBox Name="CountriesComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer in 3 years old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751419/contentcontrol-with-datatemplateselector-help-needed) from Victor. Thanks Victor.
I just need to add `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl},Path=DataContext}"` in each `DataTemplate`.